# Surface Integral without Parametrization

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $S$ be the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$.
>
> 1. Use symmetry considerations to evaluate $\iint_Sx\,dS$ without resorting to parametrizing the sphere.
> 2. Let **F** $= (1, 1, 1)$. Use symmetry to determine the vector surface integral $\iint_S$**F**$\cdot \, dS$ without parametrizing
>      the sphere.

I find it difficult to understand question 1. What does it mean by 'symmetry considerations'?

For question 2, without parametrizing the sphere, I find out that the integral should be equal to $$\frac1a \iint_S(x+y+z)dS.$$ Now symmetry comes in - a sphere is symmetric in all axes, thus the answer should be $\frac3a$ times the answer in part a. Am I correct?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrals of the form $$\iint x \, dS$$ refer to center of mass calculations. This double integral will give the $x$ coordinate of the center of mass of your surface, likewise for $y$ and $z$. However, the center of mass of a sphere is at its center, and this sphere is centered at the origin. Therefore, this surface integral is zero.

For question $2$, note that a normal vector is $(x,y,z)$. What happens when you compute ${\mathbf F} \cdot (x,y,z)$?

Comment: Thanks for replying. ${\mathbf F} \cdot (x,y,z)= x+y+z = 3 x$?

Comment: ${\mathbf F} \cdot (x,y,z) = x+y+z$, but the second inequality is not true in general. Remember you are integrating this over the sphere. Thus, what is $$\iint_S x \, dS + \iint_S y \, dS + \iint_S z \, dS?$$ Think of the considerations above.

Comment: Each integral gives the corresponding coordinate of the center of mass, but all of them must be zero for a sphere. Thus the vector surface integral is zero.

Comment: Exactly. :) Well done. A small thing is that they do not give exactly the center of mass, since we have to divide by the mass, but that's unimportant for their calculation.